# $X_{1},X_{2},...X_{n}$ i.i.d. ~ $N(\mu,\theta)$,calculate $E[X_{1}|\bar X]$

Tags: statistical-inference, conditional-expectation

$X_{1},X_{2},...X_{n}$ i.i.d. ~ $N(\mu,\theta)$, I know $E(X_{1}|\bar X)$ is UMVUE, but how can I calculate $E[X_{1}|\bar X]$, should I find the joint distribution of $X_{1}\&\bar X$? I think there is other way to do it, I have idea for continuous case, dose anyone could help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what is $\bar{X}$?

Comment: $\bar X = \frac{(X_{1}+...+X_{n})}{n}$

Comment: $X_1$ and $\bar{X} = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ are _jointly normal_ random variables with mean $\mu$ and variances $\sigma^2$ and $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ respectively. Can you find their covariance? For jointly normal random variables $U$ and $V$, $E[U\mid V]$ is well-known, and probably described in your textbook.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to calculate the covariance and we never learned $E(U|V)$, we just talked about the discrete case,like poisson, so I have problem on continuous case, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the one hand,
$$
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\bigg\vert \bar{X}\right]=\mathbb E\left[n\bar{X}\vert \bar{X}\right]=n\mathbb E\left[\bar{X}\vert \bar{X}\right]=n\bar{X}\tag{1}
$$

while, on the other hand,
$$
\mathbb E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\bigg\vert \bar{X}\right]= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb E\left[X_i\vert \bar{X}\right]=n\mathbb E\left[X_1\vert \bar{X}\right]\,.\tag{2}
$$

Therefore,

> $$
> \mathbb E\left[X_1\vert \bar{X}\right]=\bar{X}
> $$

Comment: Sweet method, thank you very much